# Format date to Portuguese in Velocity file

Tags: java, date, datetime, tomcat, velocity

I have a web application that sends out an email containing details about an event.  The email uses a Velocity template sent by a Java backend.  This application is hosted on a Tomcat server located in Brazil.

When the event date is included in the email I see the following

```
Data e Horário da Conferência (Conference Date):  Mon Feb 05 10:45:00 BRST 2018
```

Since the application is hosted in Brazil, the date/time and timezone are correct, however I would like to print the date out like:

```
Data e Horário da Conferência (Conference Date):  Seg 05 Fev 10:45:00 BRST 2018
```

Notice the spelling of the day and month.

Is there a way to achieve this in the Velocity file or in Java?  Or is it possible that I need to change some Tomcat settings?

Example:

```
-Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Duser.country=BR -Duser.language=pt"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use velocity's DateTool which is part of [velocity tools](http://velocity.apache.org/download.cgi#tools) (jar)

> The methods of this tool are highly interconnected, and overriding key methods provides an easy way to create subclasses that use a non-default format, calendar, locale, or timezone.

Add it to context of velocity:

```
context.put("date", new DateTool());
```

and then use [toDate/format](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html) functions

> format(String format, Object obj, Locale locale)
>   Converts the specified object to a date and returns a formatted string representing that date in the specified Locale.

```
$date.format(....)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is much appreciated!  Let me see if I can accomplish this with the above functions.

Comment: Instead of translating the text of 'Mon' and 'Feb' to 'Seg' and 'Fev' respectively, I used your method to output the date in the format that this locale uses:  #if($schedStart) $dateTool.format("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", $schedStart) #end

Comment: I could not figure out how to translate the actual text values using this method.  I would still like to figure out how to do this, however I believe the different formatting will work for this specific instance.  Thank you!